# GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Permanent fix PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-js-client

I am trying to fetch content from the GAPI it works sometimes but the other times it throws this error:

> Exception GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error:
>   "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps "

I browsed through all the answers but couldn't find a solution.
I tried using both of these links previously:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

It used to work but not anymore, can someone help?

Comment: mine also stopped working a while ago, wondering why.

Comment: We need to upgrade to Oauth2 but Google PHP Client Library got lots of sub libraries that actually unnecessary. Why do we need fitness.php or adsense.php to use Analytics API? So I tried Wanzes Analytics API but it doesn't work either. github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP 
I think we need a stable and lightweight API just for Google Analytics.

Comment: GAPI has been released at version 2.0 with OAuth2 support. Please see new [Github project](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Failed to authenticate user

Means there is something wrong with your authentication.

[GAPI](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) hasn't been worked on since 2009.  It also appears to use client login which was discontinued / shutdown on [April 20 2015](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable).  You can no longer use client login with Google Analytics API, you need to switch to Oauth2 or a service account.   So either the author of that project needs to fix his code, it appears to be an open source project so you could probably fix it for him.

In my opinion [Google PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) probably a better solution.

**tutorials**:

1. My Tutorial [Google Analytics API php Oauth2](http://daimto.com/google-oauth2-php)
2. My Tutorial [Google Analytics api php service account](http://daimto.com/google_service_account_php)
3. Googles Tutorial [embedded api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/)

Comment: tutorials: http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/  http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/

Comment: @DalmTo thanks for your reply, so, you're saying I cannot use the client login `new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);` anymore ?

Comment: That is correct you cant use client login (login / password) with Google analytics anymore.  If its your own account and your own data I suggest you look at a service account.

Comment: *April 20, 2012..not 2015..

Comment: it was deprecated on May 19, 2014 it was shutdown on April 20, 2015 https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable @Coderanonymous there is a different between deprecated and actually shut down.   Google gives us a little warning before they shut it down.

Comment: @DaImTo creating a service account worked, thanks a lot :)