# GAPI user authentication error

Tags: google-analytics

I am using GAPI and getting the following error. I have tried enabling the secure access of apps and used different users. But I am not getting any solution. Please help me to solve this.

Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error: "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Permanent fix PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474122/gapi-failed-to-authenticate-user-permanent-fix-php)

Comment: Duplicate of [GAPI is Shutting Down Need A Lightweight PHP API for Google Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477341/gapi-is-shutting-down-need-a-lightweight-php-api-for-google-analytics/30486524#30486524). GAPI Version 2.0 has been released with support for OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

Google have discontinued GAPI and you now have to use OAuth2
Causing me a headache as our old server only has php 5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Like other said, GAPI has been deprecated, and now you ought to use either OAuth2 or Service account. The second option is a lot easier if you need to work with your own data.

I have a tutorial that explains how to use Service account to access the Google Analytics API. [Google service accounts and PHP](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/)