# Google Analytics API authentication

Tags: authentication, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I was using this code until yesterday:

```
$gaemail = 'my email';
$gapassword = 'my password';
$gaprofileid = 'my profile id';

require 'gapi.php';

$ga = new gapi($gaemail,$gapassword);
```

Today it started giving me the error:

**Exception: GAPI: Failed to authenticate user.**

**Error**: "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps " in C:\wamp\www\projects\gapi.php on line 418

Was there any changes recently regarding the authentication process?

Comment: This problem was due to the change in the authentication method (ClientLogin to OAuth). Following the instructions in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php?hl=pt-br solved my problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Permanent fix PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474122/gapi-failed-to-authenticate-user-permanent-fix-php)

> GAPI hasn't been worked on since 2009. It also appears to use client
>   login which was discontinued / shutdown on April 20 2015. You can no
>   longer use client login with Google Analytics API, you need to switch
>   to Oauth2 or a service account. So either the author of that project
>   needs to fix his code, it appears to be an open source project so you
>   could probably fix it for him.

You have a couple of choices. Looks like the **latest version of GAPI** now has oauth support - see: https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface or use the **Google API PHP Client** (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used the gapi.php from github with the authentication StigM mentioned and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Version 2.0 on GitHub](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) of the GAPI has been released which support OAuth2 authentication. Google has disabled all other forms of authentication.

Note that OAuth2 will require you to [create a 'service account'](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) and then download a P12 file to upload to the server. Finally you will need to adjust the developers console, enable 'analytics API'. Finally give this new user 'Read and Analyse' permissions on the Google Analytics accounts you want to access.